# Match a string, skip if it has a . (DOT) infront of the result

Tags: sed

Here's what I use to match a string in a variable and delete the line where the match exists:

`sed -i '/'"$domainAndSuffix.cfg"'/d' /etc/file`

I'd like to know how to match a string in a variable, but if the match in the file has a . adjacent to it on the immediate left, then it will NOT delete this line and keep going through the file until it finds a match without a .

Sample file Contents:

*happy.domain.com

pappy.domain.com

domain.com*

String to match:
 
*domain.com*

Desired File Output:

*happy.domain.com

pappy.domain.com*

***Edit:
Actual File Contents:**

```
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/bob.ca.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/therecord.com.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/events.therecord.com.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/read.therecord.com.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/wheels.ca.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/used-vehicle-search.autos.ca.msn.com.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/womensweekendshow.com.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/yorkregion.com.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/yourclassifieds.ca.cfg
```

Comment: Here's what I have done:

`sed -in '/\.'"$domainAndSuffix"'/p' /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg`<br><br>

File Contents:<br><br>

_cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/chat.jbodyperformance.com.cfg_<br>
_cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/jbodyperformance.com.cfg_<br>
<br>
Output:<br><br>

_cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/chat.jbodyperformance.com.cfg_<br>
_cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/chat.jbodyperformance.com.cfg_<br>
_cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/http_url/jbodyperformance.com.cfg_<br>
<br><br>
Interesting results...

Comment: Should this be a comment on my answer? `-i` should be the last option,  in your case `n` can be interpreted as a suffix. Try `-ni` instead of `-in`.

Comment: Im sorry, yes that was supposed to be a comment on your comment!  Trying again. :)

Comment: It worked! But it wiped out the rest of the file contents.. :(  Perhaps I wasn't clear at the begining.. a million apologies.

Comment: What I ran: `sed -ni '/\.'"$domainAndSuffix"'/p' /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg` with `$domainAndSuffix = "jbodyperformance.com"`

File Contents: 

morestuff.jbodyperformance.com
test.com
happy.com
chat.jbodyperformance.com
jbodyperformance.com

File Contents After:

jbodyperformance.com

Comment: My bad. I'll delete my answer and post again if I have a working idea. Meanwhile you can use the [edit] link to include the actual file sample in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the preceding substring is fixed, you can try the following:

```
PREFIX='cfg_file=\/etc\/nagios\/objects\/http_url\/'
DOMAIN='therecord.com'
sed -i "/^${PREFIX}${DOMAIN}/d" file
```

If it is not fixed, it would be nice to use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but `sed` can't do that. You can use `ssed` or `GNU grep`:

```
ssed -Ri '/(?<!\.)'"$DOMAIN"'.cfg/d' file
```

or

```
grep -vP '(?<!\.)'"$DOMAIN" > file1; mv file1 file
```

Comment: @Beta Yes. It's better to forget it first than to apply prematurely :)

Comment: Ill give it a shot momentarily